# Drawing any function's graph using Javascript

Tags: javascript, plot, turtle-graphics

I'm taking a javascript class for my bachelor in CS, and the IDE we're using (it's an educative IDE developed by one of the graduates here, called [codeboot](http://codeboot.org/)) has a "turtle drawing" feature. Basically, it works using several basic commands;

Forward; fd(x), Back; bk(x), rotate right; rt(x), rotate left; lt(x), pen up; pu() and pen down; pd(). Where *x* represent pixels.

For example, to have it draw a circle, one would write something like:

```js
for (var n = 0; n < 360; n++) {
  fd(1);
  rt(1);
}
```

I'm trying to have it draw graphs for basic functions,but the only way I found how to do it is to have it draw a single point for each 0.005x (so it looks like a continuous line when zoomed out), but it makes the execution extremely slow, and you can kind of see it's not legit. How would I go about having just a continuous line instead of individually plotting each point?

Screenshot of what it looks like using my first technique:
[Screenshot of what it looks like using my first technique:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5voF2.png)

and the JS code for said technique:

```js
var x = -9;

var traceDown = function(d) {
  var y = Math.cos(x) * 30;
  setpw(3);
  pu();
  fd(y);
  pd();
  fd(1);
  pu();
  bk(1 + (y));
  rt(90);
  fd(d);
  lt(90);
  pd();
  x += 0.0005;

};

pu();
lt(90);
fd(90);
lt(90);
fd(45);
pd();
rt(180);

while (x < 9) {

  traceDown(0.005);
}
```

Comment: A turtle drawing environment is just not the best fit for a function plotter. Yes, you can do it, but it's likely awkward and/or inefficient.

Comment: It's purely for educative purposes. I'm just curious as to how I could do it, given the tools that I have.

Comment: Is there a function to get the current coordinates of the turtle?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The turtle stays where it was directed after each command. In this case, I used pen up, back(same value as the fd I used), pen down to reset the position after drawing.

Comment: To make a continous line, you'll have to compute direction and distance to the next point (the vector in polar coordinates basically), but just moving will accumulate errors. It's probably good enough for educative purposes, though.